# Json writing combination?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2010, qt

I have Qt 4.8 and I have already added the hand cpp files of json (since I am not working with Qt5). I would like to have a json format like what is follow:

data = "{average: 14, level: AA}"

The value=14 is computed from the function that I have established:

```
int average=0;
average_calc(int mark1, int mark2, int & average);
```

AA is a level that I am having from a list of choice if loop
AA is stored in a variable called:

```
string StrLevel;
```

Then, what are the steps to establish that json writing

Comment: The [Boost property tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) library have a nice [JSON reader/writer class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.json_parser_hpp).

Comment: I have no clue how to use that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to Qt 5.0 you should use QJson library. See the [Usage](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/usage/) page, it contains a simple serialization example that can be easily adapted for your case.

Comment: I already have mentioned that I m using a pevious version of Qt 5. It would be great if you read again my question above and formulate your answer again according to the asked question.

Comment: I was talking about Qt 4.8 (I hope "prior to Qt 5.0" means that).

Answer (score 1):

I recently used other simple JSON class you can very simply add to your project. I did it specifically because I couldn't use Qt5 - I'm still stuck with 4.7 at work... Find it here: [link](https://github.com/ereilin/qt-json)

You can see in the docs how to use it. For your specific example, it should be something like this:

```
QtJson::JsonObject data;
data["average"] = 14;
data["level"] = "AA";

QByteArray output_data = Json::serialize(data);
```

This would output the following:

```
{
  "average": 14,
  "level": AA
}
```

Hope it helps.